# Using jq parse a json output to get specific properties as a new json output

Tags: amazon-web-services, unix, aws-cli, jq

I am very new to jq, I am trying to parse an output json I get from  command -

```
aws cloudformation list-stacks --stack-status-filter CREATE_COMPLETE
```

to get a new output where values of the key matches to certain pattern.

for example this is my json output from previous command -

```
{
  "StackSummaries": [
    {
      "StackId": "arn:aws:213dqwqwdqwdqwdq",
      "StackName": "monkeyman",
      "CreationTime": "2017-06-06T20:52:59.728Z",
      "StackStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE",
      "TemplateDescription": "Liaison API ELB cloud formation script"
    },
    {
      "StackId": "arn:aws:csdfsdfcsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfgdfgfdg",
      "StackName": "monkeyman2",
      "CreationTime": "2017-06-06T20:51:55.191Z",
      "StackStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE",
      "TemplateDescription": "yoohooo instance"
    },
    {
      "StackId": "arn:aws:sdffgds444fsdfsdfgdfgfdg",
      "StackName": "starfish2",
      "CreationTime": "2017-06-06T20:51:55.191Z",
      "StackStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE",
      "TemplateDescription": "helloworld instance"
    },
    {
      "StackId": "arn:aws:csdfsdfcsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfgdfgfdg",
      "StackName": "bulldog4",
      "CreationTime": "2017-06-06T20:51:55.191Z",
      "StackStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE",
      "TemplateDescription": "night night instance"
    },
    {
      "StackId": "arn:aws:yhyhyhyhyhysdfgdfgfdg",
      "StackName": "carrotman",
      "CreationTime": "2017-06-06T20:51:55.191Z",
      "StackStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE",
      "TemplateDescription": "surprise mo instance"
    }

  ]

}
```

Here I need to create a new output json by piping the first output to jq where StackName startsWith **monkeyman** and **bulldog** and which should look like -

```
{
  "StackSummaries": [
    {
      "StackId": "arn:aws:213dqwqwdqwdqwdq",
      "StackName": "monkeyman",
      "CreationTime": "2017-06-06T20:52:59.728Z",
      "StackStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE",
      "TemplateDescription": "Liaison API ELB cloud formation script"
    },
    {
      "StackId": "arn:aws:csdfsdfcsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfgdfgfdg",
      "StackName": "monkeyman2",
      "CreationTime": "2017-06-06T20:51:55.191Z",
      "StackStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE",
      "TemplateDescription": "yoohooo instance"
    },
    {
      "StackId": "arn:aws:csdfsdfcsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfgdfgfdg",
      "StackName": "bulldog4",
      "CreationTime": "2017-06-06T20:51:55.191Z",
      "StackStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE",
      "TemplateDescription": "night night instance"
    }

  ]

}
```

I have tried a lot, I was able to do it somehow using basic unix split and regex commands but something tells me it would be easier and less cumbersome to do directly with jq.

Comment: Amazon supports this natively. We don't need 'jq' to achieve this. Refer this link: http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/07/27/advanced-aws-cli-jmespath-query/ which explains how to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *is* easy with jq

```
jq '.[] |= map(select(.StackName | startswith("monkeyman"), startswith("bulldog")))'
```

In a nutshell, map(x) applies x to every object that is fed to it. select(y) selects the objects that meet the condition y. In this case, condition y is that there is a key called StackName whose value starts with either "monkeyman" or "bulldog".